# accessing a file inside war folder from a code

Tags: java, configuration, war

I am finding it hard to access a file inside my `war`folder from a code in my java web project.

This is my file structure

[image]

the java code I am using is inside the package `com.abl.tf.dao`.

I am trying to access the the file `testreport.jrxml` which is inside the `war->reports`  folder.

This is what I have tried and this gives me the exception `file not found`.

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JasperDesign design = JRXmlLoader.load(
                    new LegacyJasperInputStream(new FileInputStream("/TFProject/reports/testreport.jrxml"))
                    );
```

could you please help me to access that file from the code.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the file as a resource. You do it like so:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JasperDesign design = JRXmlLoader.load(new LegacyJasperInputStream(getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/reports/testreport.jrxml"));
```

Comment: in which library jar this comes with. I am on a Spring project.

Comment: and I am not coding inside a jsp page. this is inside a java code

Comment: If you are using Spring then you can get the servlet context like this: @Autowired
ServletContext servletContext;